# How to disable hard link to /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, security, etcpasswd

I am learning security recently, and noticed that on my experiment system I can create a hard link to /etc/passwd in my home directory, while on my work system I cannot:

$ ln /etc/passwd
ln: failed to create hard link `./passwd' =>`/etc/passwd': Operation not permitted

What is done to disable this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for questions about programming. Your question may be suited for unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: And I don't get why making hard link to `/etc/passwd` is a security issue...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch depending on the version of *nix it is an issue as /etc/passwd was where passwords were stored back in the day.

Comment: No, hard-linking a file don't give more or less access to it. You can read it independently of the number of hard links.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to create hardlink to `/etc/passwd` on a different volume. Most likely at your home system you setup everything onto a single volume.

Comment: That's not the reason. They are on the same volume.